# Smoothed line scatter plot in excel 2016 deviates from true titration curve

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am plotting multiple acid base titrations in excel which exhibit x=y^3 inflection curves, essentially sideways cubic "S" curves.  When I have excel connect the data points with a smooth curve, this happens:

[titration curve deviation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HRUfV.jpg)

How do I fix the bulge at the bottom of the inflection points?